# Encoding a Boolean raster from polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rasterization

Polygons become invisible when rasterised, and raster has very odd values. Can I correct this so raster has 1 for polygon and 0 for non-polygon?

I have drawn polygons over a feature for a species occupancy model, and have found that the software for this requires that my environmental variables be in raster form. When I try to rasterise my polygons in QGIS, I get an odd result. It says that there is a value of between -3.40282e+38 to 3.40282e+38 for these rasters.

I did not give any values to the polygons, I just created them! Additionally, when I have it so that only the newly rasterised version of the pisciculture is present, there is nothing on the map.

What happened to the polygons I created?

Is there any way to make a raster that just has an output of 1 where my polygons are drawn and an output of 0 where they are not in the extent that I specify?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the settings/parameters you use when rasterizing?

Comment: Not sure how to show the screenshot here, but this is what I have. For input layer I have the layer with my polygons. For all burn in and fixed layer to burn I have not put in a preferance since I do not know what they mean. For output raster size I have pixels, which are 1.5 x 1.5 in resolution. Any less and I got an error message saying that I did not have enough space to do the rasterization. I have not said anything about nodatalayer in bands. I have set output layer as extent when over relevant region.